# How can I read this particular buffer data that I'm getting from arduino while using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, arduino, buffer, sensors, pulse

I'm currently using a pulse sensor on an arduino, and trying to get data from the sensor and trying to display it on the browser. This is what my nodejs code looks like.

```js
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/cu.usbserial-DA011OXR", {
  baudrate: 57600
});

serialPort.on('open', showPortOpen);
serialPort.on('data', saveLatestData);
serialPort.on('close', showPortClose);
serialPort.on('error', showError);

function showPortOpen() {
   console.log('port open. Data rate: ' + serialPort.options.baudRate);
}
 
function showPortClose() {
   console.log('port closed.');
}
 
function showError(error) {
   console.log('Serial port error: ' + error);
}

function saveLatestData(data) {
   console.log(data);
   latestData = data;
}
```

And this is the kind of data I'm getting on the terminal.

```js
<Buffer 53 35 31 34 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 33 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 31 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 30 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 31 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 31 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 31 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 32 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 32 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 33 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 34 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 34 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 34 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 34 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 34 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 33 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 32 0d 0a>
<Buffer 53 35 31 31 0d 0a>
```

I've been trying to look on the web how I should interpret or parse this data, but I'm pretty clueless. Any help would be great!

Comment: Since `data` is a `Buffer` object, just call a `toString()` on it, like `console.log(data.toString())`.

Comment: You should probably look at the arduino docs and see just what you are getting, i.e. the format of the output data. By default Buffer.toString() treats the buffer as utf-8 encoded text, which may well be incorrect; maybe (e.g.) you are getting a 6-byte signal and you need to turn it into a Number.

Answer (score 0):

Set right baudrate. in my case it was 9600.
If you make something like `Serial.println(dataFromPin)` you could
`data.toString('ascii')`

How could you guess encoding: `data[0].toString()` and compare with values from arduino IDE Serial Monitor.